# Filemaker If PatternCount calculation not working

Tags: filemaker, calculated-field

I have a calculation field in Filemaker that is not giving me an error but is not populating the checkbox either.  I need to put a Yes in the checkbox if the string "Friday lunch through Sunday lunch" is contained a field and not if it isn't.  Here is my Filemaker calculation:

```
  mealdeal = If (PatternCount ( registration2016::full_receipt ; "Friday lunch through Sunday lunch"); "Yes"; "No")
```

I  have not worked with Filemaker much and can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: There's not enough information here to identify the problem. Make sure the result type of the calculation is set to Text, then observe the result in a field formatted as edit box.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it appears correctly as yes or no.  Would a screen shot of the calculation window be of help?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working now as it should.  I want to give credit to michael.hor257k for enlightening me to an easy way to test it.  I suspect the problem was a refresh issue.